# Finding the solution to a third-order linear homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation to solve is: $(4D^3+27D^2+70D+39)y=0$

My first step is to identify the characteristic equation :
$4D^3+27D^2+70D+39$

Then, I find the roots of the characteristic equation. There is only one root: -3/4.

Finally, I find the complimentary solution: $y = C_{1}e^{-3x/4}$

I have also verified that placing this complimentary solution into the original differential equation does indeed equal 0.

Can I consider that I have solved this differential equation? I am confused as to whether or not I need to find a particular solution for this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  There is only one *real* root...

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I see. Is this where the "3 cases" come into play ? First case: the equation has real and distinct roots. Second case: the equation has real and non-distinct roots.Third case: the equation has non-real roots. Therefore, this equation needs to be solved using the method for the third case?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Nevermind, I have found the relevant explanation in my text book. Thank you for pointing me towards real roots !

Comment: No, the solution is $$y=C_1 e^{-\frac{3 x}{4}}+C_2 e^{-3 x} \sin 2x+C_3 e^{-3 x} \cos 2x$$

Comment: @Raffaele Yep, thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next you extract the factor $4D+3$ to get the deflated quadratic polynomial,
$$\begin{align}
4D^3+27D^2+70D+39&=(4D+3)D^2+24D^2+70D+39\\
&=(4D+3)(D^2+6D)+52D+39\\
&=(4D+3)(D^2+6D+13)
\end{align}$$
Then find the roots of the quadratic equation $0=D^2+6D+13=(D+3)^2+4$ etc.